# JTextPane doesn't display text during breakpoint debugging

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, event-dispatch-thread

I am new to Java/Swing. I have this code:

```
private void printText(String msg)
{
    jStatus.setText(msg);        
    jStatus.setCaretPosition(jStatus.getText().length()-1);
}
```

`jStatus` is the `JTextPane`. I want to use that in debugging. 
However, the `msg` doesn't display on `jStatus` till the program gets out from breakpoint.

Is it possible? Or I should use `System.out.print` instead?

Comment: And where the that shadow breakpoint is?

Comment: Don't block the EDT, the GUI will freeze up.  Instead use a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever debugging technique you are using, there should be also possibilities to step into/over/out from instruction points. And if you want your text to be visile in the Swing component when your debugger stops, you should setup a break point in the just-next instruction to you desired point which is:

```
jStatus.setCaretPosition(jStatus.getText().length()-1);
```

Now if your debugger stops in that line and you can't see the text in your `JTextArea` that means there should be some issue and you should move up the tree your breakpoint and digg into methods following the stack.

`System.out.print`, `System.err.print` or whatever standard console output/error you use, is not related that much to debugging. It is just an instruction that let you print your Objects states in the console so you can see them in realtime. That being said, it is allowed or better adviced to be used only in development and for real production system, you should consider a [logging solution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html).

So to sum up, you can keep as many `System.out.print` instructions as you want and step up into debugging your source code.